# Testing a component using a custom DatePipe

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have a custom pipe extending DatePipe for formatting a string to a specific date format.

```
// FormateTimePipe.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({
    name: 'time'
})
export class FormatTimePipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    override transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        value = `${new Date().toDateString()} ${value.replaceAll('.', ':')}`;
        return super.transform(value, args);
    }
}
```

I tried to write unit test cases for the component that is using this custom pipe.

```
// amendment-list-dropdown-spec.ts

import { FormatTimePipe } from '@agic/shared/pipes/formateTime.pipe';
import { PadZeroPipe } from '@agic/shared/pipes/padZero.pipe';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CustomDropdownComponent } from '@motorcycle/components/common/custom-dropdown/custom-dropdown.component';
import { AmendmentListDropdownComponent } from './amendment-list-dropdown.component';
export function findComponent<T>(fixture: ComponentFixture<T>, selector: string): DebugElement {
    return fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector));
}
describe('AmendmentListDropdownComponent', () => {
    let component: AmendmentListDropdownComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AmendmentListDropdownComponent>;
    const padZeroPipe: PadZeroPipe = new PadZeroPipe();
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AmendmentListDropdownComponent,
            CustomDropdownComponent, PadZeroPipe, FormatTimePipe ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AmendmentListDropdownComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('should bind the configured value', () => {
        const customDD = findComponent(fixture, 'custom-dropdown');
        const customDDComponent = customDD.componentInstance;
        const display = customDD.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-button span.dropdown-value span');
        const listItem = component.amendmentList.data[0];
        expect(display.textContent).toBe(`Amendment: ${padZeroPipe.transform(listItem.attributes.amendmentSequence)} ${listItem.attributes.amendmentType} : ${listItem.attributes.amendmentTypeDescription}`);
        customDDComponent.currentValue = component.amendmentList.data[1];
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            const selected = customDDComponent.currentValue;
            expect(display.textContent).toBe(`Amendment: ${padZeroPipe.transform(selected.attributes.amendmentSequence)} ${selected.attributes.amendmentType} : ${selected.attributes.amendmentTypeDescription}`);
        });
    });
});
```

I am getting the below error when running the test case:

```
TypeError: Class constructor DatePipe cannot be invoked without 'new'
      at new FormatTimePipe (packages/shared/pipes/formateTime.pipe.ts:351:43)
      at FormatTimePipe_Factory (ng:\FormatTimePipe\ɵfac.js:5:10)
      at ɵɵpipe (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:22715:30)
      at AmendmentListDropdownComponent_ng_template_3_div_1_Template (ng:/AmendmentListDropdownComponent.js:36:5)
      at executeTemplate (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:12121:9)
      at renderView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:11921:13)
      at TemplateRef2.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:23143:9)
      at ViewContainerRef2.createEmbeddedView (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:23261:37)
      at node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2020/common.mjs:3225:31
      at DefaultIterableDiffer.forEachOperation (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:28558:17)
      at NgForOf._applyChanges (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2020/common.mjs:3220:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly more testable variant of the pipe would be injecting the `DatePipe` instead of extending it:

```js
export class FormatTimePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  override transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    value = `${new Date().toDateString()} ${value.replaceAll('.', ':')}`;
    return this.datePipe.transform(value, args);
  }
}
```

You'll have to register `DatePipe` as a provider in order for it to work:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    FormatTimePipe
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
    DatePipe
  ]
})

// in the TestBed too
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [..., FormatTimePipe],
  providers: [..., DatePipe]
```